# How can I delete a file that doesn't have a matching file with a different extension

Tags: bash, file-management, file-manipulation

It's a bit hard to expliain, but I'm looking for a relatively easy bash script that can delete a file if it doesn't find a file of the same name that is an mp4.

Essentially I have files like:

```
S01E02 - Name of Episode 2.description
S01E02 - Name of Episode 2.srt
S01E02 - Name of Episode 2.mp4    
S01E03 - Name of Episode 3.description
S01E03 - Name of Episode 3.srt
S01E03 - Name of Episode 3.mp4
S01E04 - Name of Episode 4.description
S01E04 - Name of Episode 4.srt
```

What I'm trying to accomplish would be to get a bash script setup that can search the files and delete files such as:

```
S01E04 - Name of Episode 4.description
S01E04 - Name of Episode 4.srt
```

because there is no matching mp4 file

I only started fooling around with bash a week or so ago so I'm sure it's far easier than I'm making it out to be, but I just can't figure it out myself.

---

I was thinking of using a for command, but I can't wrap my head around how to identify if the file being looked at has a match or not. I honestly haven't tried much because I can't even think of where to start.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For the record, this would be a better question if it included the code you'd tried to use, and the precise error encountered from that code -- providing only a specification for a program you want written, and not a [mcve] of a specific problem you encountered in the process of writing it yourself -- can come across as a "please write my code for me" request. See discussion @ [What close reason should I use for "give me teh codez"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253137/what-close-reason-should-i-use-for-give-me-teh-codez) on [meta].

Comment: ...while this specific question doesn't look like homework, the general guidance in [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/14122) applies: You should ask about a **specific problem** with your **existing implementation**.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers @CharlesDuffy. Still new and my stack overflow etiquette is a bit lacking, but I'll definitely keep it in mind for next time. Again, appreciate the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for file in *; do
  [[ $file = *.mp4 ]] && continue  # skip .mp4 files
  mp4_file=${file%.*}.mp4
  [[ -s $mp4_file ]] || rm -f -- "$file"
done
```

Let's look at how this works:

- `${file%.*}` is a [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) which strips the shortest string matching `.*` from the end of the variable `file`. `mp4_file` thus has the extension-less name, with `.mp4` appended.
- `test -s "$mp4_file"`, or its modern-bash-syntax alternative `[[ -s $mp4_file ]]`, looks at whether a file thus-named exists and is not empty.
- `foo || bar` executes `bar` if and only if `foo` returns a boolean-false value.

Thus, the effect is to loop over files in the current directory, skipping ones that end in `.mp4`, look for paired or matching `.mp4` files, and delete files for which no matching `.mp4` is found.

Comment: Thanks so much! I honestly didn't expect an answer so quick but I really appreciate it, and thanks for breaking it down, this way I know what it's doing and I can say I learned something, not just someone did it for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob

for f in !(*.mp4)
do
 filecheck=$(echo "$f" | cut -f 1 -d '.').mp4
 if [ ! -f "${filecheck}" ]; then
   rm -- "$filecheck"
 fi
done
```

It simply iterates through the list of non .mp4 files and checks if the same filename exists with the .mp4 extension

Comment: This will behave badly with filenames with spaces or expandable wildcards in their names on account of the missing quotes; it also will look for `foo.mp4` when it sees `foo.bar.baz.something`, when correct behavior would be to look for `foo.bar.baz.mp4`.

Comment: Good point, though -- I missed that the OP wanted to do this for **all** non-`.mp4` files.

Comment: `rm -- "$filecheck"` will fix behavior with spaces, and `filecheck=${f%.*}` will fix behavior with multiple dots. (Also, the `echo $f` would need to be changed to `echo "$f"`, but that's mooted if you switch to the PE syntax). See [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo) re: passing unquoted variables to `echo`, or run the code in the answer through http://shellcheck.net/.

Comment: Indeed it's true, I tried with very simple filenames, my bad! Edited the answer (Shellcheck.net -> Didn't know it, looks awesome!)